# Blank fields when fields contain '<...>' with httpRuntime requestValidationMode

Tags: c#, validation, webforms

I use `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />` to get rid of error:

```
0x80004005 Dangerous Request.Form
```

But it replaces text that contains `<`,`>` with blank lines. Because of that my values are empty. I work on a page in intranet, so I don't worry about code injection. I know could I could encode my text with `System.HtmlEncode` when retrieving it from database, but I would have to apply it to every single row and column of my `DataTable`. Also it can sometimes convert text to html, that should not be visible as html and making many special cases for different fields doesn't seem like a clean approach to me. Is there any other way of ignoring `<...>`?

I also added `<pages validateRequest="false">`, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: At this point i'd consider reversing course. You're going way down the rabbit hole with requestValidation off; might as well fix things as you go with it turned on. 2 c.

Comment: @wazz, but how to fix this in a sensible way? A couple of columns in my database are stored as html and some are not (not my decision). So I cannot apply `Server.EncodeHtml` on every column, because some of the columns will show as plain text with html tags. I would need to go through every place in my application and convert only certain columns which is a nightmare to maintain...

Comment: Not sure. Need sleep. Hopefully someone has an easy fix soon.